# Pass json into AWS CLI Invalid JSON

Tags: json, linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-12.04, aws-cli

I have a script to add some custom metric data and it works great of i write the metric data to a file and then read that in like:

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --namespace "ec2" --metric-data file://metric2.json
```

But if i have the script just print and call it like this:

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --namespace "ec2" --metric-data $(python aws-extra-metrics.py)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--metric-data': Invalid JSON:
```

Is their any way around this i would prefer not to have to write it to a file everytime as this will be ran from a cronjob.

We are running ubunutu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is the python script generating the json file? The difference is between passing a file name and passing the file content.

You could try:

```
python aws-extra-metrics.py > metric2.json && aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --namespace "ec2" --metric-data file://metric2.json
```

or

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data --namespace "ec2" --metric-data $(python aws-extra-metrics.py)
```

you may need quotes around the invocation of the python script